# Getting error while installing elasticsearch using brew command

Tags: elasticsearch

```
bhanu.palampalle@P66QWC7XT3 ~ % brew install elastic/tap/elasticsearch-full
```

> Error: elastic/tap/elasticsearch-full: undefined method `require_root' for nil:NilClass

Could you please provide me the steps to resolve this and get it installed in my local machine.